# Show particular point topology, is a topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I'm teaching my self topology with the aid of a book. I'm trying to prove the following is a topology:

> Let X be an infinite set, and $p$ be an arbitrary point in $X$.
>  Show that $\mathscr{T}_3=\{U \subseteq X : U = \varnothing $ or $ p \in U \} $ is a topology.

My book calls this the [particular point topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology)

Please let me know if my proof is valid.

Now to verify the definition.

> (i) X and Ø are elements of $\mathscr{T}$.

Ø is given in the definition of $\mathscr{T}_3$, and $p \in X$, by definition. So (i) is "self-evident."

> (ii) $\mathscr{T}$ is closed under finite intersections.

Let: $ A = \bigcap_{i=1}^n U_i ; $ where $U_i$ are sets that contain $p$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I'm going to prove by contradiction. Assume $A \notin \mathscr{T}_3 $; that would imply that $p \notin A$, and by the nature of intersections, that would mean that AT LEAST ONE of the $U_i$'s does not contain $p$. However that contradicts the definition of $U_i$ ([RAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum)).

> (iii) $\mathscr{T}$ is closed under arbitrary unions.

Let: $A=\bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$ where $U_i$ are sets that contain $p$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I'm going to prove by contradiction. Assume $A \notin \mathscr{T}_3 $;that would imply that $p \notin A$, and by the nature of unions, that would mean that ALL OF the $U_i$'s do not contain $p$. However that contradicts the definition of $U_i$ ([RAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but perhaps you will find this pair of comments useful:

- There is no need for $X$ to be infinite. It suffices to be non-empty. Note that you have never used that $X$ is infinite.
- Try to rewrite the two last proofs without using RAA. This is an extremely useful technique, but RAA make these particular proofs unnecessarily long and "overloaded".

Comment: thanks, i just did it without RAA. It seems like when ever I use RAA to prove something, someone comments that its better to not use contradiction. To me RAA seems more straight forward, but that doesn't seem to be the way most people see it.

Comment: RAA is perfect for *many* proofs, but not for every one. Don't take it as a taboo. But use it when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

@ajotatxe, here is my attempt to prove (ii) and (iii) without RAA.

> (ii) $\mathscr{T}$ is closed under finite intersections.

Let: $ A = \bigcap_{i=1}^n U_i ; $ where $U_i$ are sets that contain $p$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. $A$ must be in $\mathscr{T}_3$ because intersections are the points that sets have in common, and every $U_i$ contains $p$.

> (iii) $\mathscr{T}$ is closed under arbitrary unions.

Let: $A=\bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$ where $U_i$ are sets that contain $p$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. $A$ will be in $\mathscr{T}_3$ if at least one of the $U_i$'s contain $p$. And, in fact, all the $U_i$'s contain $p$. So $A \in \mathscr{T}_3$.

Comment: This is almost perfect, but you need to account for the possibility that at least one of the $U_{i}$ is empty in each case. In (ii), it just means $A = \emptyset$, and in (iii), either all the $U_{i}$ are empty (in which case $A = \emptyset$ or at least one $U_{i}$ contains $p$, in which case $A$ contains $p$.